# Populate UITableView with Array not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to embed a UITableView in my View Controller (not a TableViewController). 
I am unable to get any of my data to show. 
Here is the relevant code:

M file:

```
@interface ViewController () <CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray        *Device_array_name;

@end
```

.
.
.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


   cell.textLabel.text=self.Device_array_name[indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}
```

I've also defined number of sections and rows, and my array does indeed have content. I'm pretty new to iOS development so I've no doubt missed something.

Thanks

Comment: Is your `numberOfRowsInSection` method being called? Does it return a non-zero value? Is `tableView` non-nil? Is its `delegate` and `dataSource` set properly? Is the table view's frame set properly?

Comment: where you allocating  and adding objects in `Device_array_name` array ? please try to reload table after adding data in array.

Answer (score 6):

Delegates & Datasources should be defined for UI Controls to get called their respective delegates.

For Instance : In your `viewDidLoad` function define

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.datasource = self
```

It will work.

Answer (score 2):

Set the array allocation in your view did load.

```
Device_array_name=[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Set the tableview delegates in viewdidLoad

```
tableview.delegate=self;
tableview.datasource=self;
```

After give the count of an array in Number of rows in section

```
return Device_array_name.count;
```

In your cellForRow AtIndexpath method

```
  cell.textLabel.text=[self.Device_array_name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be 4 reason (most probably)

1> You delegate and datasource are not set

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.datasource = self
```

2> Your datasource array is nil (Device_array_name)

3> Your IBOutlet is not connected with tableview

4> Your tableview frame is becoming zero due to autloayout or something else (check console at runtime)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to initialize the **delegate** and **dataSource** for your **tableView** property to your ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

If you embed this way, you don't have default setting for the `UITableView` like you have when you use `UITableViewController` directly. You will need to set it up by yourself. Most likely, it's because you have not wired up your delegation object. Second will be, your `UITableView` is invisible. That also causes the problem because the delegate methods will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

i think go to storyborad and set delegate,datasource in there.if you using by storyborad.i hope will work.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYDDA.png]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my list of the possible problems:

1. The `@IBOutlet` for the table view is not connected in Interface Builder. **Solution:** check connection in Interface Builder.
2. The outlet *is* set, but the view controller placed in the storyboard is not of your custom `UIViewController` subclass, but the default `UIViewController`. In this case, none of your code will be executed. **Solution:** specify the view controller's class is the identity inspector (center tab).
3. The `dataSource` property of the table view is not set to your view controller. **Solution:** Assign it in either Interface Builder (storyboard) or programmatically inside `viewDidLoad()` or later.
4. You are not implementing the `UITableviewDataSource` protocol method: 
   `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` (i.e., the table view "thinks" it has 0 rows to display). In this case, `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` will not be called *(you can confirm this by placing a break point).* **Solution:** Implement the method and return the `count` property of your model object array.
5. The array that serves as the data source for your table view is empty (has zero elements). **Solution:** Make sure the array contains your model objects.

I might have left some other common mistake out... Let me know.

---

**Addendum:** Unless you have [a compelling reason not to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14465669/433373), I would **strongly** suggest that you use a stock `UITableViewController` instead of manually adding a `UITableView` to a plain `UIViewController`. You get a lot of functionality and setup for free.