# Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'tableView'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the error:

> Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'tableView'

occur when I attempt to change the background of the tableView in the `viewWillAppear` method.

I expected the table view would already be initialised from the `viewDidLoad` method.

Where should I be trying to change the colours for the tableview? Should I also be changing the other background colours in the same place?

```
class settingsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Table view setup
    let tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .Plain)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.registerClass(settingsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(settingsCell))
    view.addSubview(tableView)

  }

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    if nightMode == true {
      view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
      view.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor() // Error here..
    }
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return settings.count
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(NSStringFromClass(settingsCell), forIndexPath: indexPath) as! settingsCell

    // Fetch setting
    let cellSetting = settings[indexPath.row]

    // Configure Cell
    cell.textLabel?.text = cellSetting.name

    return cell
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose not to use `UITableViewController` or at least an instance variable?

Comment: You've got your tableView locally scoped. Put it toward the top outside of viewDidLoad. As it stands, only viewDidLoad "sees" it. See Bhavin's answer for deets

Comment: I'm mostly doing this for practise, at the UIViewController requires me to do more things manually I think. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465447/are-there-any-advantages-to-using-a-uitableviewcontroller-over-a-uiviewcontrolle

Comment: Thanks Adrian and Bhavin, I see the tableView only existed inside the viewDidLoad function. For academic interest, was the error because tableView would be dropped from compliler's memory once viewDidLoad is complete? Or because the XCode couldn't see that viewDidLoad was going to run before viewWillAppear and it actually should have worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it an instance variable of `UITableView` like

```
 class settingsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

 var tableView:UITableView!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      // Table view setup
      tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .Plain)
      tableView.delegate = self
      tableView.dataSource = self
      tableView.registerClass(settingsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(settingsCell))
      view.addSubview(tableView)
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(true)

     if nightMode == true {
         view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
         tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
     }
}
```

Comment: 1) This doesn't define `tableView` "globally" (that has a different meaning). This makes it an instance variable. 2) No need to create the temporary `UITableView` instance when you declare the instance variable.

Comment: I'm far from fluent in Swift but shouldn't the declaration of the `tableView` instance variable just be `var tableView:UITableView`? Why add the `= UITableView()` part?

Comment: The `= UITableView()` creates a new table view. But then you create another in `viewDidLoad`. There's no point in creating that initial table view.

Comment: @rmaddy without fully declaring the tableView I get error unwrapping a nil value when attempting to access the tableView.background. Therefore, I   declared the variable table view, removed the second declaration in viewDidLoad and amended the frame to view.bounds in viewDidLoad. Bhavin suggest your original solution was correct with these changes to viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1):

This is not the right way of accessing a subview within a view. You can use [`viewWithTag:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/viewWithTag:) to get the subview  by tag:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  ...
  tableView.tag = 100
  view.addSubview(tableView)
}

...

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  ...
  if let tableView = view.viewWithTag(100) {
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you make `tableView` an instance variable if you need to access it in more than just `viewWillAppear`:

```
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController ... {
    var tableView: UITableView!
    ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      ...
      self.tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .Plain)
      ...
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
      ...
      self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
}
```

Comment: Or make `tableView` an instance variable. That would be much better since it is likely the code will need to access the `tableView` in more than just `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the tableview in global value, then use the tableview in class, see the below code,

```
     class ViewController: UIViewController {
            var tableView = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        tableview.frame = self.view.bounds
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.registerClass(settingsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(settingsCell))
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
      }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
            if nightMode == true {
                view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor() 
      }
}
```

hope its helpful

Comment: Why have you included the IBOutlets?