# In which case do you use UIViewController class with UITableViewDelegate/UITableViewDataSource protocols instead of straight UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uivewcontroller

I ask because I've just downloaded two example swift projects: one is a todo-list, the other is a contacts list, both use `UIViewController` class conformed to `UITableViewDelegate/UITableViewDataSource` protocols instead of `UITableViewController`. Is there anything different between those two practice at all?

in code:
`class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {...}`

vs.

`class ViewController: UITableViewController {...}`

Comment: yes the diff is you can change tableview size in UIViewController but you can do that in UITableveiwController:P

Comment: do more research on google. you must look at this awsome answer :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465447/are-there-any-advantages-to-using-a-uitableviewcontroller-over-a-uiviewcontrolle