# What are the benefits of using tableView within a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

What advantages do I have when using tableView inside UIViewController not using UITableViewController?

Comment: The static cells requires a `UITableViewController`.

Comment: Check @maddy's answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465447/are-there-any-advantages-to-using-a-uitableviewcontroller-over-a-uiviewcontrolle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- Ability to customize the tableView height and width as you want

2- Ability to have more than 1 tableView instead of only one with UITableViewController

3- When adding a subview it's added to self.view which won't make that subview scroll with tableView like in UITableViewController

Answer (score 0):

In `UITableViewController` you may have only UITableView and no other UI elements. In `UIViewController` you may have anything you want. Basically, you need  `UITableViewController` only if you have only static content and only one view - `UITableView`.