# Pros and cons of using UITableViewController vs putting UITableView inside UIViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am designing an tab bar / navigation style app and I've added TableViews using both methods.  Is there a preferred method and what are the pros and cons of using a UITableViewController vs putting UITableView inside UIViewController

I will need navigation item bars on top, informational labels, and navigation buttons on the bottom.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UITableViewController vs TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694185/uitableviewcontroller-vs-tableview)

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewController can have static cells.  TableView in a ViewController cannot.

Your labels will scroll with the tableview if you use a TableViewController unless you implement extra code to prevent it.  With a UITableView the labels on top would stay in place automatically when scrolling.

Navigation Bar on top will always remain on top regardless.

Comment: Are we talking about the same static cells? Because I'm pretty sure it's possible for both of them.

Comment: "One more thing about static cells: they only work in UITableViewController."  taken from: https://www.raywenderlich.com/113394/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-2

Comment: Unless something has changed in the most recent update of Xcode they will not work in a UITableView only UITableViewController.

Comment: Actually, at this very moment, I'm working in an `UIViewController` where I've manually added an `UITableView` with static cells. Perhaps it's not possible using the storyboard, because I usually do everything programmatically.

Comment: Storyboards will let you add them and then give you an error when you try to build.  If you want static content you can just create a prototype use it once and never change it.  It becomes more of an issue if you want to add something like a UITextField to your cell.  This is something I tried in the past and was forced to use a UITableViewController with static cells.